# Can Assign two Pods in Replication Controller to the two Different Nodes on Kubernetes?

Tags: controller, docker, replication, kubernetes

There are two containers defined in my Replication Controller config file and the value of replicas is 1, Is there any way to assign two Pods  to the two different nodes?

Answer (score 0):

When you define two containers in a single Pod, they will always be co-scheduled onto the same node (regardless of whether you define the Pod directly or via a Replication Controller). The number of replicas for the Replication Controller is the number of Pods to run (not the number of containers).

Comment: Yes, So Is there any way to assigns two nodes to run each container in a single Pod?